# Android static App Shortcut is not showing

Tags: android, android-shortcut

I created app shortcut as specified in https://developer.android.com/preview/shortcuts.html. Despite running on API 25 and Pixel launcher, app shortcut is not showing on launcher screen. What might be the cause?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using reference (@string) as `shortcutId` results in app shortcut silently not showing up.

Comment: thank you, I spent almost an hour trying to debug this. Incredibly annoying that Google hasn't documented it.

Comment: @yuval it took some time but apparently they did: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37124066 points to updated docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.html that (imo) still don't put enough stress on the fact that you need to be cautious because they didn't feel like writing a parser for refs.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation because I couldn't find solution. Why only some smartphones has the bug and not others ?

Comment: When i click on the shortcut i'm getting app not installed message. What could be the reason for this ?

Comment: For me the problem was I did not set a `shortcutId` at all

Answer (score 0):

Check this

Only main activities—activities that handle the **Intent.ACTION_MAIN** action and the **Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER** category—can have shortcuts. If an app has multiple main activities, you need to define the set of shortcuts for each activity.